# How can I control the speed that bootstrap carousel slides in items?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I see you can set the interval but I want to control how fast the items slide?

```
   // Sets interval...what is transition slide speed?
    $('#mainCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000
});
```

Comment: Googlers --> to slow down INTERVAL (time between showing next image)::: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203373/1985648

Comment: In case if you are looking for Angular solution, please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927344/add-interval-for-each-mdb-carousel-item-in-angular/67947718#67947718)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The speed cannot be controlled by the API. Though you can modify CSS that is in charge of that.
In the `carousel.less` file find

```
.item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    .transition(.6s ease-in-out left);
}
```

and change `.6s` to whatever you want.

---

In case you do not use .less, find in the `bootstrap.css` file:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

and change `0.6s` to the time you want. You also might want to edit time in the function call below:

```
.emulateTransitionEnd(2000)
```

at `bootstrap.js` in function `Carousel.prototype.slide`. That synchronize transition and prevent slide to disapear before transition ends.

**EDIT 7/8/2014**

As @YellowShark pointed out the edits in JS are not needed anymore. Only apply css changes.

**EDIT 20/8/2015**
Now, after you edit your css file, you just need to edit CAROUSEL.TRANSITION_DURATION (in bootstrap.js) or c.TRANSITION_DURATION (if you use bootstrap.min.js) and to change the value inside it (600 for default). The final value must be the same that you put in your css file( for example 10s in css = 10000 in .js)

**EDIT 16/01/2018**
For Bootstrap 4, to change the transition time to e.g., 2 seconds, add

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = 2000  // 2 seconds
});
```

to your site's JS file, and

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  transition: transform 2s ease, -webkit-transform 2s ease;
}
```

to your site's CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried putting the latter in my styles of my main .html page and changed the .6 to .1 and it didn't seem to have no effect using chrome.

Comment: Not clear... did you try to modify bootstrap files or did you just add this stuff into your own css? It's safer to edit bootstrap files. Otherwise you need to make sure that your styles load last and overwrite bootstrap styles.

Comment: My styles were possibly loading last.  However, my defined css styles in my main html page are defined after I include the link to include bootstrap.css. Either way modifying within bootstrap worked. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly in Bootstrap 3. The slides flash disappear before they have finished moving.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you do NOT have to modify any javaScript (anymore), [that line in the code now pulls the .css('transition-duration') value](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L388), so you just need to add some CSS as described above, and that's it. (Also, be sure the carousel item has the "slide" class, not sure that's mentioned in the docs.)

Comment: This answer worked for me, but the ideal way to do it is in a separate CSS file, overriding the default BS transition. You ONLY need the transition style info in your override definition.

Comment: There are like 10 finds of `.emulateTransitionEnd` in bootstrap.js, most of them on their own line.  In my case all of these have different values.  Not sure which one, or if all of them are supposed to be changed to the millisecond of the transition?

Comment: `.carousel-inner > .item {` works fine without `position: relative;` and `display: none;`.

Comment: In Bootstrap 3 (v3.3.5, anyway) the JS no longer pulls that duration value from CSS. It can be easily set *without modifying Bootstrap* like so: `jQuery.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1000;`

Comment: I only have bootstrap.js min so this task is a bit more difficult to do. Could I just skip change in js and apply only in css?

Comment: jQuery.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION returns undefined. How does one change it? The transition works and it slides slowly, but the image that slides out gets display: none; too quickly.

Comment: Please note  that since Bootstrap 4.0 it is `.carousel-item` and not just `.item`. Also not all CSS instructions are needed as provided in this solution to archive the desired affect. Only `transition` without a dot is required.

Comment: it should not be this hard to change the transition

Comment: While this answer is obviously correct. I cant help but think this is too much work to achieve the desired goal. K.I.S.S should be the motto. Answers below seem to be more suited to a standard approach to a simple problem like this.

Comment: I'm a bit late but changing only the css transition property seems adequate why bother with js ?

Answer (score 115):

Just write `data-interval` in the `div` containing the carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="500">
```

Example taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel_interval_data&stacked=h).

Comment: Please try to format your question in a more proper way. Btw. link only are not considered as good answers.

Comment: Warning: the "data-interval" is measured in miliseconds. 500 = 0,5 sec (so much fast). If you have some text to show on slides, 10000 (10secs) is better.

Works fine. I think that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is **incorrect**. `data-interval` determines the time span after which new slide moves. It doesn't determine how much time one slide takes to move.

Comment: Thanks dude, it saved my day. +1 and this should be checked as right answer rather than going to edit bootstrap.css file.

Comment: As well save a lot of time. Thx

Comment: I was looking for THIS exact answer... but tried the other answer before, before I realized that that had to do with the slide speed, while this answer deals with the intervals between the slides. So thank you for including this answer, since this was exactly what I wanted! (even though 500 is too fast, but that's a different story)

Comment: Do you know how to set the interval per slide?

Comment: Best answer! Working with Bootstrap 4 (Oct 2018)

Comment: Please be aware that from bootstrap 5, it is `data-bs-interval`(see one of the answers down below). `data-interval` does not seem to work anymore for bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 14):

You need to set interval in the main DIV as data-interval tag.  The it will work fine and you can give different time to different slides.

```
<div class="carousel" data-interval="5000">
```

Comment: Can you provide an example. I need to give different time interval for diff slides and these are configured in my controller returned from an api call. Can we show web pages using slider as well?

Comment: data-interval determines the time span after which new slide moves, not the animation duration.

Answer (score 12):

For Twitter Bootstrap 3:

You must change the CSS transition as specified in the other answer:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

From 0.6 seconds to 1.5 seconds (for example).

But also, there is some Javascript to change. In the bootstrap.js there is a line:

```
.emulateTransitionEnd(600)
```

This should be changed to the corresponding amount of milliseconds. So for 1.5 seconds you would change the number to 1500:

```
.emulateTransitionEnd(1500)
```

Answer (score 12):

With Bootstrap 4, just use this CSS:

```
.carousel .carousel-item {
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Change `3s` to the duration of your choice.

Comment: very very nice :)

Answer (score 10):

One thing I noticed is that Bootstrap 3 is adding the styles with both a `.6s` and `0.6s`. So you may need to explicitly define your transition duration like this (CSS)

```
    .carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.9s ease-in-out left;
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s, ease-in-out, left;
    -moz-transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
    -o-transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
    transition: .9s, ease-in-out, left;
    }
```

Comment: Not work for me :( it's still roll fast as a car with no change (I changed to 1.6)

Answer (score 8):

for me worked to add this at the end of my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myCarousel").carousel({
         interval : 8000,
         pause: false
     });
});
</script>
```

it gives to the carousel an interval of 8 seconds

Answer (score 7):

no need any external code just use `data-interval=""` attribute

more information visit [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options)

`<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2500">`

when you want change speed change "2500"

Answer (score 4):

For bootstrap 4 with scss, you can overwrite the configuration variable `$carousel-transition-duration` in your `_variables.scss` like this:

```
$carousel-transition-duration: 2s;
```

Or for element individual duration set the

```
.carousel-item {
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

of your specific element in your css/scss.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do it programmatically to change (for example) the speed based on certain conditions on perhaps only one of many carousels, you could do something like this:

If the Html is like this:

```
<div id="theSlidesList" class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div id="Slide_00" class="item active"> ...
  <div id="Slide_01" class="item"> ...
  ...
</div>
```

JavaScript would be like this:

```
$( "#theSlidesList" ).find( ".item" ).css( "-webkit-transition", "transform 1.9s ease-in-out 0s" ).css( "transition", "transform 1.9s ease-in-out 0s" )
```

Add more .css( ... ) to include other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

after including `bootstrap.min.js` or uncompressed one, you can just add interval as a parameter as below 
`jQuery("#numbers").carousel({'interval':900 });` It works for me

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change the js files of bootstrap, you can also directly inject the wanted value into the jquery plugin (bootsrap 3.3.6).

This requires of course, that the carousel is activated manually via js, not directly via the data-ride attribute.

For example:

```
var interval = 3500;
$.fn.carousel.Constructor.TRANSITION_DURATION = interval - 500;
elem.carousel({
    interval : interval
});
```

Comment: I like this approach because it does not requires you to edit `bootstrap.js`, and making it "unupdateable"..

Comment: After changing to 200, i don't see the smooth animation anymore, the images are gonna disapear right in the middle of transition

Comment: Hi @TomSawyer - the animations are maintained via the css, but it is important, that the TRANSITON_DURATION is long enough, to cover the full transition. in the javascript it just defines, when the ```in``` class is set, and when it is removed again. If you want to shorten the animation, please check, where it is defined in the less files.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to edit the speed in which the slides come in and out (not the time in between changing slides called interval) for bootstrap 3.3.5 | After loading CDN bootstrap styles, overwrite the styles in your own css styleseet using the following classes.  the 1.5 is the time change.

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
-webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out ;
-o-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out ;
transition: 1.5s ease-in-out ;
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
transition: transform 1.5s ease-in-out;

}
```

after that, you will need to replace the carousel function in javascript. To do this you will overwrite the default bootstrap.min.js function after it loads. (In my opinion it is not a good idea to overwrite bootstrap files directly).
so create a mynewscript.js and load it after bootstrap.min.js and add the new carousel function.   The only line you will want to edit is this one, Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1500.   1500 being 1.5.  Hope this helps.

```
    +function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      = null
    this.sliding     = null
    this.interval    = null
    this.$active     = null
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.5'

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 1500

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active)
    var willWrap = (direction == 'prev' && activeIndex === 0)
                || (direction == 'next' && activeIndex == (this.$items.length - 1))
    if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos) }) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
          }, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {
      $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide-to]', clickHandler)

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of two answers provided me with the styling i was looking for.

`data-interval` attr did not work AT ALL for me in bootstrap 5. I also do not store bootstrap locally

To slow down the time from ONE slide to another

Sites CSS file.

```css
.carousel-item {
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

To slow down the delay BEFORE moving to the next slide

Sites JS file

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 15000
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Bootstrap 5**, add **data-bs-interval="6000"** attribute like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="6000">
```

Carousel items change every 6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the previous answers, after you edit your CSS file, you just need to edit `CAROUSEL.TRANSITION_DURATION` (in *bootstrap.js*) or `c.TRANSITION_DURATION` (if you use *bootstrap.min.js*) and to change the value inside it (600 for default). The final value must be the same that you put in your CSS file (for example, 10s in CSS = 10000 in .js)

```
Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.2'
Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = xxxxx /* Your number here*/
Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
interval: 5000 /* you could change this value too, but to add data-interval="xxxx" to your html it's fine too*/
pause: 'hover',
wrap: true,
keyboard: true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to change **interval** in **bootstrap.js**

```
  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 2000,      // <----- change this
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }
```

Comment: That controls the frequency of animations, not the speed of an individual animation.

Answer (score 2):

All  carousel

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 15000
            })
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide explanation with answer

Comment: Once again this simply determines the interval, not the transition time

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
    transition-duration: 1.5s, 1.5s;
}
```

Take care, the time is included in data-interval defined for the carousel.

Hope it helps... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
```

Just add `data-interval="1000"` where next picture will be after 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Add Data interval

```
data-interval="20000"
```

Answer (score 1):

use `data-interval="2000"` like below

1000  = 1 sec

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-custom" data-`ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">`
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the ngCarousel module, edit the interval variable in the file @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel-config.js like so:

```
var NgbCarouselConfig = /** @class */ (function () {
function NgbCarouselConfig() {
    this.interval = 10000;
    this.wrap = true;
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main.js file or bootstrap.js, change the value of ***autoplayTimeout***

```js
    $('.carousel').each(function () {
        $(this).owlCarousel({
            nav: $(this).data('nav'),
            dots: $(this).data('dots'),
            loop: $(this).data('loop'),
            margin: $(this).data('space'),
            center: $(this).data('center'),
            dotsSpeed: $(this).data('speed'),
            autoplay: $(this).data('autoplay'),
            transitionStyle: $(this).data('transition'),
            animateOut: $(this).data('animate-out'),
            animateIn: $(this).data('animate-in'),
            autoplayTimeout: 3000,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                },
                400: {
                    items: $(this).data('slide-sm'),
                },
                700: {
                    items: $(this).data('slide-md'),
                },
                1000: {
                    items: $(this).data('slide'),
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
    transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    transition: transform 2s ease;
    transition: transform 2s ease, -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
    -o-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
}
```

accepted answer works but this and only this also works... why bother with js ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if nothing works for you.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"></div>
```

1000 is 1 second, and 3000 is 3 seconds. You can replace ‘3000’ with your desired slider speed.

Below is the css you can change the speed:

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

To see the full post, take a look at
[this post here](https://blog.identitydesign.us/bootstrap-carousel-slider-transition-speed-time-interval/).

Answer (score 0):

This is incredible that people answer about interval, this is not at all what the question is about ! Interval is the amount of time to delay between automatically cycling an item :
[Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#options)

The good answer is the css transition duration :

```
.carousel-item {
    transition-duration: .2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me version 5.3: -

1. Add data-bs-ride="carousel" where id="carouselExampleInterval"

   class="carousel slide"  data-bs-ride="carousel">
2. Add data-bs-interval="5000" to all carousel-item (your choice how long time you want)

class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="5000">

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap version 5 instead of `data-interval` use `data-bs-interval`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="500">
```

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap 4.1, this can be achieved only by adding:

```
$carousel-transition-duration: 2s; // or some duration length
```

in your custom SASS variable and compiled.