# How to disable bootstrap carousel animation?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

For example I have carousel with 3 images, when the carousel slides the new images are added via 'slid' event

```
$('#imageCarousel').on('slid', function (event) {
      //add more images
});
```

I want to disable animation for the carousel, so transition time is set to 0 in carousel css as it was shown here [removing carousel animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items). But after that 'slid' event does not fire. I cannot use 'slide' event, because I need to know which item is active in the carousel, but the 'active' class is not set up after the 'slide' event. How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I suppose you can use the following code,

just remove the `slide` class from `carousel` div and use like,

```
<div class="carousel">
```

this will remove the slide animation effect, see the working [fiddle](http://bootply.com/80526),

Comment: No, interval it is time between cycling an item, I already use it. I'm interesting in removing animation during sliding (.carousel('next'))

Comment: you mean, want to stop the next & prev?

Comment: I mean the next(previous) image should be shown instantly when next(previous) function is called, without slide animation

Comment: ok, got the answer, just remove the "slide" class, for example, instead of this <div class="carousel slide"> use <div class="carousel"> see the fiddle http://bootply.com/80513

Comment: maybe I didn't get something, but 'slid' event still doesn't work in your example.

Comment: you just add the following in the javascript part of that example,$('#carousel-761238').on('slid', function (event) {
      alert('message');
});. here is the new example with slide event http://bootply.com/80526

Comment: ok, it works, I used bootply in a wrong way. Please update your answer (removing the slide class) and I will mark it as accepted, maybe it will be helpful for someone else. Thanks!