# Bootstrap carousel removes previous item too soon

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically, I modified the carousel CSS so that the transition is 1s instead of 0.6s. What happens now is that after 0.6 the previous image is removed and placed at the end of the line (cycle is on).

Is there any way to delay this as well?

Comment: At the very minimum, show us your modifications. We've got nothing here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I control the speed that bootstrap carousel slides in items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items)