# how to slow down scrolling speed of moving bootstrap carousel slides with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a fullscreen bootstrap carousel site. I use scroll for changing slides, but it goes to fast. How can I slow scroll speed down? I use this code:

```
$('#mycarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e)
    {
        if(event.wheelDelta<0) {
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }else if(event.wheelDelta>0){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: The code shown has nothing to do with the problem, i.e. how fast/slow will carousel('next/prev') transition to the new state.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The code binds mousewheel event with changing the carousel slides (instead of button). But it works too fast (on laptop it goes through 5 elements in one "swipe" on touchpad). I would like to know if there is a way to make it slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much a hack, but should work by firing scroll only at intervals of 5 scrolls

```
    $('#mycarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e)
        {
            if(typeof(this.deltasum) == 'undefined'){this.deltasum = 0;}
// On chrome each scroll delta is +-120. Testing if this is cross browser
            this.deltaSum +=event.wheelDelta; // Value will be attached to DOM object


            if(event.wheelDelta<0 && this.deltaSum % 240 === 0) { // only fire if sum is divisible by 120
                $(this).carousel('next');
            }else if(event.wheelDelta>0 && this.deltaSum % 240 === 0){
                $(this).carousel('prev');
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work. I tried the same thing with a loop and it also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on this site, src: [How can I control the speed that bootstrap carousel slides in items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items)

The speed cannot be controlled by the api. Though you can modify css that is in charge of that. In the carousel.less file find

```
.item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    .transition(.6s ease-in-out left);
}
```

and change 6s to whatever you want.

In case you do not use .less, find in the bootstrap.css file:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

and change 0.6s to the time you want. You also might want to edit time in the function call below:

```
.emulateTransitionEnd(2000) 
at bootstrap.js in function Carousel.prototype.slide. That synchronize transition and prevent slide to disapear before transition ends.
```