# Bootstrap slider is not moving smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a carousel slider using bootstrap.

Here is my code:

```
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/ndn5u1rf3/home_slider1.jpg one');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/6sk4s4pov/home_slider2.jpg two');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/uktg3nrpr/home_slider3.jpg three');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/uschmfdan/home_slider4.jpg four');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

It works fine, but I need something like [this](http://alterid.com). On this website, the slider moves smoothly.. but in my code it doesn't work like this.

Can anyone help me fix this? Is there a modification I could make to this code?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean increasing transition time, you may want to have look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items

Comment: did you see my website link?.. thanks

Comment: The link doesn't work...

Comment: @RamtinGh: Yeah your link is correct . thanks..

Comment: @Okx: I got it.. thanks

Comment: @Okx: I got it it work slider perfectly.. but these source only in header tag.. and i need to add logo,title and buttons on the slider.. Like this link.. http://www.alertid.com/default_v5.asp