# HTML Automatic Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an automatic slideshow that covers the whole page and changes photos every 4 seconds, i have this codepen set up for testing but i have no clue whats wrong with it. 
There is 5 images im currently using and i want it to just change every couple of seconds if possible, I am using bootstrap 3 on the ASP.NET project but it doesn't interfere with anything i do to the slideshow

https://codepen.io/xElectric/pen/poomKQw

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vX8LONV.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/a9bx26U.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PijASuc.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vX8LONV.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/c8AjEXg.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/srhebZH.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The error message means the list of "dot" elements is empty. There are no elements with class="dot" in  the source.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 Is it possible to make it automatic with the carousel?

Comment: Fix with @MrLister solution for you to see: https://jsfiddle.net/5kg14cr8/

Comment: instead of nesting the `setTimeout`, it would be much much better to use a single `setInterval`.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 thanks, but i think that making the carousel will make it look nicer. after its fully automatic

Comment: @LukaszHumeniuk did you get, what was the issue? in the JS code you are trying to access `dot` class elements which are absent in provided HTML code. that was breaking snippet.

Comment: @LukaszHumeniuk No worries, the BS carousel is already automatic; and you can just delete the relevant HTML to remove the dots and other indicators if needed. Have a look at **[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items)** to see how to speed up the slides.

Comment: @Harish I forgot to get rid of the get dots in js which was causing it to break and also setInterval instead of setTimeout fixed it, Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote some useless code in you snippet, which you don't need like dot, dot div you don't have in your HTML code,

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots =   document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }

  slideIndex++;
  
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vX8LONV.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/a9bx26U.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PijASuc.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vX8LONV.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/c8AjEXg.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>
          <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/srhebZH.jpg" style="width:100vw;">
            </div>

        </div>
  
  
    </div>
```

if you need any help please inform us!

Happy codin'!